# Using Google Places API in Swift for displaying names of the places around

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-places-api, google-places

I am looking into the tutorial made by Google about displaying places on the map with `swift` (link is here: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-places-tutorial#find-nearby-places-and-represent-them-with-markers-on-the-map ). Their code says that I can display markers on the map with additional information:

```
func updateMarkers() {
  mapView.clear()
  placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
      return
    }

    if let likelihoodList = placeLikelihoods {
      for likelihood in likelihoodList.likelihoods {
        let place = likelihood.place

        // Add markers for nearby places.
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: place.coordinate)
        marker.title = place.name
        marker.snippet = place.formattedAddress
        marker.map = self.mapView
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I want to display to the user names of the places around, but not put it on the map - just put it in a `UITableView`.

Is there a way that Google's API takes the longitude, latitude and e.g. radius and returns me the list of names of places around that I could display in the console?

Comment: just store your one place information in NSMutabledictionary and add that dictionary value into NSMutablearray and that array value display in console or in tableview .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya thanks for the hint, but as for now I don't know even how to fetch this information, I'm not using MapKit or GoogleMaps in my app, so I need to send location as a parameter

Comment: other user location how can you get ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I already have user's location fetched thanks to `locationManager`, now I need to pass somehow the lon/lat to the Google services

Comment: your question totally confuse me please clear it with more details